# Arquillian - some external jar issues

Tags: eclipse, ant, classnotfoundexception, jboss-arquillian

My first time doing any testing other than simple JUnit test. I have Arquillian set up on a very old EJB2.0 Ant project and I'm hitting a dead end here.

Set up with Arquillian:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addPackages(true, "com.admin", "com.framework", "com.pharmacy")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

    EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class)
            .as(ZipImporter.class)
            .importFrom(new File("C:\\jboss-4.2.3.GA\\server\\default\\administration.ear"))
            .as(EnterpriseArchive.class);

    ear.addAsLibrary(jar);
    return ear;
}
```

I'm able to hit the container, get the data source and query the tables. However, if I'm running a test that uses codes that depends on other JARs, or if the test code itself depends on other JARs, then I'm getting the ClassNotFoundException.

For example, in my test case, I'm trying to make an HTTP request using `httpclient-4.5.2.jar` and `httpcore-4.4.4.jar`, then I'm getting `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext` inside the Eclipse junit test console. I have these jars in my Eclipse classpath, and it's working when I run this same HTTP test using Codehaus Cargo framework.

Another example, I'm initialize a class instance, and this class instance makes an sftp call using apache's vfs2 jar. Then I get this error inside the jboss server.log: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSelector`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since Arquillian is an isolation, I suppose you need to include the external classes in your Java archive.

```
JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
        .addPackages(true, "com.admin", "com.framework", "com.pharmacy")
        .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
        //
        // You need to include to external classes used
        // in your Java archive using addClass / addClasses
        //
        .addClasses(ExtA.class, ExtB.class)
        //
        // or the entire package if needed
        //
        .addPackage(true, "my.ext.package");
```

Then the deployment should work.